# Pg_pool and Slony together for Postgresql Cluster setup

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, slony

we have 4 postgresql servers. Is it good idea to setup slony replication in 3 nodes(1 master and 2 nodes)  and pgpool for load balancing with master node???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought SNONY is for master-master replication... If you have master-slave better use simple STREAMING REPLICATION

Comment: No, slony is also used for Master-slave replication

Comment: Yes, apparently it is master-several slaves replication with possible cascade... So then why not "bit-to-bit" streaming replication?..

Comment: seems good. 
Will u please explain differences between slony and in built streaming replication...

Comment: there are 3 main features - all are on main page of SLONY :) plus the FAILOVER process is different

Comment: Can we achive this only with pgpool?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember pgpool allows you to not only distribute load among slaves but making automatic FAILOVER as well. They have it on their main page as well :)

Comment: PLease conclude it, what should i do with that 4 nodes??
Also with some explaination

Answer (score 0):

All depends on what are you setting up. If you need partial or more sophisticated replication, you should choose SLONY. It is great product. On the other hang if you want "bit-to-bit" exact ReadOnly slaves to be replicated from one master, you don't need SLONY much. Another thing to consider - [automatic failover](http://slony.info/documentation/2.0/failover.html). [STREAMING REPLICATION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html) does not provide it. You can write a script that will do it for you though. Another option to use [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#stream) which automates the process. Plus pgpool can perform load balancing and more flexible network architecture. The last thing to mention is [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) which can help you to have network architecture flexibility and security running DB. Ah yes, not to mention some commercial products like [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/) that can be the easiest solution for small project without DBA...

It is only you who can make a choice. Good luck!